# Align a photoshop layer top with another layers bottom

Tags: adobe-photoshop, alignment

I thought this would be an easy google but I can't find it anywhere.

Lets say I have 2 layers, A and B.  They are both rectangles.  I want them stacked on top of each other with 0 pixels in between so:

```
=======
=  A  =
=======
=  B  =
=======
```

Is there a simple way to align the TOP of a layer (layer B) with the BOTTOM of another layer (layer A).

I would love to just drag objects in, horizontally center them, and then have them bump right up to another layer above or below it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can remember, there is no straight forward (select layers, click one button) way of doing this, but one simple solution of doing it is to pull a guideline that will stick to the bottom of object A and then drag object B toward the guideline which will make it stick to it. And there you have it.

Comment: Thats a shame.  I have multiple artboards where I am dropping and adding blocks all over the place.  Dropping and having guidelines all over the place would just create a mess.  Ill just have to fine eye ball it like always. Thanks though.

Comment: Well, after you align them you have no need for the guideline and you can just remove it.

Comment: I guess so, just feels like a rather disruptive step in a workflow. I'll give it a shot anyways though.  Thanks

Comment: Good luck, it's a 4 click method which is not that bad when practiced.

Comment: @ChrisShields if you're going to use this method then new PS has Guides From Layer. One of the first things I did was give that a shortcut, you might want to do the same.

Comment: @Ryan I assume you mean View->New Guide Layout?  If so then yes! This is super handy.  A combination of shortcuts and the guides will be the best solution still.  I also checked out the "Kind" filtering, and although I didn't find it as handy for my current problem, its bloody brilliant and has helped a lot just in other mundane tasks!  Cheers!

Comment: @ChrisShields I mean "New Guides from Shape" --- wonder if this is same wording on Windows, could've sworn its "..from Layer" on my office computer. Basically instead of pulling out a guideline like Alin says you can just press that. Its right under the Guide Layout function

Comment: Ok, yeah its definitely "New Guides from Shape" on OSX in PS CC. Yeah I've checked this out as well, both should come in super handy.

Answer (score 1):

...View turn on Snap, make sure Snap To Layer is one of the activated options in that same menu.

[Positioning Elements with Snapping](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/positioning-elements-snapping.html)

Comment: Snapping is great and is what I use right now to get as close as possible.  Unfortunately I have a ton of artboards and objects all over the place and the objects a layer chooses to snap too are ridiculous.  Sometimes it wants to snap to some random layer 5 artboards over and refuses to acknowledge the closest layer by proximity.  Thanks though!

Comment: @ChrisShields in that case you might want to consider using the Layer panel's more extensive features to sort and group things to then activate and deactivate

Comment: I assume you mean, groups and such. I use a lot of groups, nested groups etc..., smart objects and synced library graphics.  I don't like to disable every artboard I am not working on, as I jump between at least several of them at a time. Unless I am misunderstanding you?

Comment: I haven't used it much but with new PS there's more sorting stuff where it says "Kind" can do some more advanced sorting and grouping. Combined with Ctrl+comma and it might help speed things up a little for you. Its hard to say without seeing your design and layer panel